# Easyadmin 4 redirecting to 127.0.0.1 when i want to go to any other url

Tags: symfony, localhost, easyadmin

Hello i have my website on symfony 6 with easyadmin 4, the admin route show the dashboard, but when i want to get to any other route, edit , show etc, it redirect my to 127.0.0.1 , i dont know what matter.

i wanted to edit my entity through easyadmin

Answer (score 0):

yes, the problem was de MODSECURITY activated on server